# Google Sheets: Filtering based on a combination of previous rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on a large data set that needs to be filtered based on the value of the previous two rows. The goal is: if the previous two rows are <=1.15 then return current row. So the following data round get filtered down to 1.88. I haven't been able to find any guide that digs in the weeds of how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Multiplier
2.8
6.55
1.1
1.06
1.88
1.89
2.36
8.23

Answer (score 0):

Here'a a more "manual" and "once-off" way of approaching this. How I'd do it is use the next column to filter out the values. See formula in pic attached. Then copy-paste column B by *values only*, then sort it to get rid of the blank spaces. For a *better* way, I've used the *filter* function in a separate answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create three extra columns.

Cell B1's formula is just `=A2` (and populate it down). Cell C1's formula is similarly `=B2`. So these columns are just putting three adjacent cells into a convenient row.

Then fill in formula as shown in screenshot in cell D1. No need to 'pull' D1 down. The `filter` function automatically populates down and removes blanks.

*I edited the data a bit just to get two results out of it, not only one.*

[image]